# Hide rows based on text cell values in either of two different columns

Tags: excel, vba, hide, rows

I hide all rows with the value "Kitchen" in column 8.

I also need to hide the row if column 12 contains "No". This is an "Or" statement, not an "And" statement.

I have researched the site, but have not been able to find the answer. I would also like to speed up the process.

```
Sub FOHc()

    BeginRow = 6
    EndRow = 400
    ChkCol = 8

    For RowCnt = BeginRow To EndRow
        If Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).Value = "Kitchen" Or Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).Value = Blank Then
            Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).EntireRow.Hidden = True

        Else
            Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).EntireRow.Hidden = False

        End If
    Next RowCnt

End Sub
```

[image: Spreadsheet]

Answer (score 1):

You can just add one more `Or` condition

```
If Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).Value = "Kitchen" Or Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).Value = Blank Or Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol2).Value = "No" Then
```

For speeding up macro, add `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` at the beginning and `Application.ScreenUpdating = True` at the end. This will stop updating your screen while proceeding macro.

Answer (score 1):

To add another logic test, simply add another `Or` statement.

To speed up collect all rows to hide in a range, and hide them in one go.

Also in general it's a good idea to use proper qualifiers, the statement `Cells` refers to what Excel considers to be the active sheet. while `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells` always refers to the sheet called "Sheet1".

Declaring all variables may prevent unwanted behavior and bugs and in general is good practice.

Here is the refactored code.

```
Sub FOHc()
    Dim beginRow As Long
    Dim endRow As Long
    Dim chkCol As Long
    Dim rowCnt As Long
    Dim rngResult As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    beginRow = 6
    endRow = 400
    chkCol = 8

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'Change this to the actual name of your sheet.

    With ws
        .Cells.EntireRow.Hidden = False 'Unhides all rows, remove line if that's not desired
        For rowCnt = beginRow To endRow
            If .Cells(rowCnt, chkCol) = "Kitchen" Or .Cells(rowCnt, chkCol) = Empty Or .Cells(rowCnt, 12) = "No" Then
                If rngResult Is Nothing Then
                    Set rngResult = .Cells(rowCnt, 1)
                Else
                    Set rngResult = Union(rngResult, .Cells(rowCnt, 1))
                End If
            End If
        Next rowCnt
    End With

    If Not rngResult Is Nothing Then rngResult.EntireRow.Hidden = True

End Sub
```